# My while is just broken

Tags: python-2.7

Ok so im new to python 2.7.5 and my code is just not seeming to work.
Its just a basic random number guessing 'game'

```
from random import randint
number = randint(1,100)
play = input("Hello! Would you like to play (Y/N) ")
if play in('y','Y'):
    print("I've chosen a number between 1 and 100.")
    guess = int(input("what is my number?")
    while(guess != number):
        if(guess > number):
            print("Too High!")
        else:
            print("Too Low!")
        guess = int(input("Please guess again: "))
    print("Correct! You guessed my number!")
if play in('n','N'):
    print('Stop wasting my time then!')
```

Im getting an error that is highlighting while and saying its an "Invalid syntax"
and help will be gladly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a parenthesis on this line:

```
guess = int(input("what is my number?")
```

You opened two, but only closed one.

The solution is to close both:

```
guess = int(input("what is my number?"))
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct since it solved your problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Missing parenthesis was the problem. But you should use raw_input() instead of input().

```
from random import randint
number = randint(1,100)
play = raw_input("Hello! Would you like to play (Y/N) ")
if play in('y','Y'):
    print("I've chosen a number between 1 and 100.")
    guess = int(raw_input("what is my number?"))
        while(guess != number):
            if(guess > number):
                print("Too High!")
            else:
                print("Too Low!")
            guess = int(raw_input("Please guess again: "))
        print("Correct! You guessed my number!")
if play in('n','N'):
    print('Stop wasting my time then!')
```